# UI/Tree Node doesn't update on RadTreeListView

Tags: wpf, telerik, treelistview

I have an application which is using RadTreeListView to bind and display as a tree. The ItemSource is binded from ViewModel with type is RadObservableCollection and declared:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding HistoryList, Mode=TwoWay,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,
NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
```

The issue is when I add a new node to HistoryList then call RaisePropertyChange of HistoryList, the UI of RadTreeListView doesn't update even though the data added.

```
this.HistoryList.Add(treeViewItem);
this.RaisePropertyChanged(x => x.HistoryList);
```

Then if I use reset() method of RadObservableCollection, the UI is updated but float top the top of view. So the question is how can I handle with it? I mean I wan to keep the state/position of node that I selected.. not jump or float.

This video gets better for you to understand: http://screencast.com/t/iLa3XWsa

Thank you